# How can I use a large array field in django without constantly initializing it?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django application that needs to be able to serve list pages of records of a certain model, sorting based on simple fields like user, time etc.  This model, however, also needs a sometimes very large array field associated with it (could be up to 10s of megabytes or more per record in some cases), but this array data will only be used under certain circumstances, while it is not relevant any time a page is being generated.

Since loading a model object, to my knowledge, will initialize all of the fields, will this hurt my application's performance, since large amounts of data will be constantly initialized and thrown away just to generate simple list views?

Also, even if I make a separate model containing the large array data, with the original record pointing to it with a ForeignKeyField, will this not have the same problem since django will also initialize the foreign key related objects?

If there is some way of modifying the objects Manager to only load this array field under certain circumstances, I think that would be decent solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call `defer()` on a `QuerySet` which may be unnecessarily fetching large fields.
From the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer):

> In some complex data-modeling situations, your models might contain a
>   lot of fields, some of which could contain a lot of data (for example,
>   text fields), or require expensive processing to convert them to
>   Python objects. If you are using the results of a queryset in some
>   situation where you don’t know if you need those particular fields
>   when you initially fetch the data, you can tell Django not to retrieve
>   them from the database.
>
> This is done by passing the names of the fields to not load to
>   defer():

This can be done with a custom Manager if necessary, by overriding the `Manager.get_queryset()` method